# how to deploy ASP.NET project in VS2012

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment

I have started my web application project in ASP.NET using Visual Studio 2012. There is no problem in developing the project but having real problems in deploying the project. After the project is complete i have no idea how to deploy it on actual server there was provision in VS2010 but no option in VS2012. As this is my first project in VS2012 please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the project in your solution explorer and click on 'publish'. Then you get a wizard to create a publish profile.

Comment: yah but that option was available in VS2010 but there is no option like publish in VS2012

Comment: In my VS2012 there is. Are you sure you are right-clicking the project and not the solution in the solution explorer?

Comment: Actually I selected website in the wizard while first creating it .so its a collection of .aspx and aspx.cs files. Is that might be the reason for not displaying the publish option ? Website can also be published.

Comment: Ah, that's the problem. I was assuming you started a web application project. For a web site project, the publish tool is indeed unavailable. You can find more info on the difference and how to publish here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx